# Why is my form validation not working?

Tags: php, forms, validation, header, preg-match

I'm having troubles validating my form. How do I validate the form using PHP? I've tried lots of different methods and nothing has worked. I can get the inputs to display (although check-box doesn't always display) but it just won't validate.

I also want to display the user's inputs (after it has been validated) onto another page, how do I do that?

Here is my code;

Form:

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
<label for="name">Your Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" required>
<br><br>
<label for="email">Your Email:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" required>

<br>
<br>
<label for="subject">Subject:</label>
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="" required>
<br>
<br>
Recipient:
<div>
 <label for="admin">
  <input type="checkbox" name="recipient[]" id="admin"  value="Administrator">
  Administrator</label>
 <br>
 <label for="editor">
  <input type="checkbox" name="recipient[]" id="editor"  value="Content Editor">
  Content Editor</label>
  <br>
 </div>
<br>
<label for="message">Message:</label>
<br>

<textarea name="message" id="message" cols="45" rows="5" required></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Send">
<br>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];



 if ($_POST['submitted']==1) {  

        if ($_POST['name']){  
            $name = $_POST['name'];

        }  
        else{  
             echo "<p>Please enter a name.</p>" ;  
        }  

        if (preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", $email))
          $email = $_POST['email'];

        }  
        else{  
            echo "<p>Please enter a valid email.</p>";  
        } 
        if ($_POST['subject']){  
            $subject = $_POST['subject'];

        }  
        else{  
             echo "<p>Please enter a subject.</p>"; 


      if(empty($_POST['recipient'])){
        echo "<p>Please select a recipient</p>"; 
       }else{
              for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST['recipient']);$i++) {
                  echo $_POST['recipient'][$i] . " ";
              }
      } 


        }   
        if ($_POST['message']){  
            $message = $_POST['message'];

        }  


/* go to form.php
display results
echo "<strong>Your Name:</strong> ".$name. "<br />";
echo "<strong>Your Email:</strong> ".$email. "<br />";
echo "<strong>Subject:</strong> ".$subject. "<br />";
echo "<strong>Recipient:</strong> "; 
echo "<br />"; 
echo "<strong>Message:</strong> <br /> " .$message;  
*/
 ?>
```

Comment: Slow down. Ask one question at a time. **Describe what is wrong.** What problem do you have specifically?

Comment: Firstly, the validation isn't working on the email part. I have only used the validation on the email so far.

Answer (score 1):

if (preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", $email)

You can't use email in this condition because $email is empty!

Comment: I don't understand, please elaborate.

Comment: You try to match the string with $email... What is $email in this point?

Comment: oh it seems that part of the code was left out.
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

Comment: but you need to control first if the $_POST['email'] is set and if it isn't empty because you can't match something whith nothing :D

Comment: I tried the one in the link you provided but it still doesn't work. 
This is the error message which now comes up; "Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier ',' in E:\xampp\htdocs\jokeCMS\contact.php on line 81"

Comment: replace the end of preg_match with +(.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", $email)